# Is gpflow's scaled_euclid_dist as stable as tensorflow_probabilities?

Tags: gpflow

Basically, for kernels that depend on `r` the L2 norm is calculated [here](https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/blob/master/gpflow/kernels.py#L288) and one sees we first clip the value. In [tensorflow probability](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/tensorflow_probability/python/positive_semidefinite_kernels/internal/util.py#L88) they use a `sqrt` with a modified gradient that replaces `grad(|x - x'|)` with a large but finite number when `x=x'`. 
My question is whether they are equivalent, or if one is better?

Answer (score 0):

I've checked gradients for GPflow clipped version for `x=x'`. The result surprises, as it is zero. I did expect it to be high value.

Simple check confirms that gradient of `tf.sqrt(1e-40)` should return `5.e+19`, and I'm not sure that clipped version has right behaviour.

Comment: That is surprising that the gradient goes to zero. It must be due to the clipping. The good thing is that we likely want grad(sqrt(x^2)) -> 0 when x is zero. The clipping is avoiding a NaN as it should, because normally one would get 0*Inf if no modification was done. The difference that tensorflow_probability makes is that they change Inf to a large number when x=x'. I think there is a difference between the two methods for numbers 0 < x <= 1e-40, because the gradient should only be chosen as zero exactly when x==0.